# how to create dynamic navigation in zend frameworks 2

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-navigation

i am new to the zend framework and using zend framework2.
I have to create dynamic navigation(fetching menu from the database) in zend framework2?

I searched it out alot but i am not able to do that.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Actually i have deleted the code. Do you have some idea how can i do that with an example

Comment: http://www.jaapsblog.nl/blog/view/35/zf2-creating-a-dynamic-navigation.html

Comment: I use this url but getting an error

Comment: In that case my friend you have to provide us the code that you tired and the error message which you got.

Comment: Thanx my friends i got the result.
Thanx alot.